# In R: How to name a vector so that the name shows up when using lm()

Tags: r, vector, naming, lm

In R, how do I change the name of a vector, such that the vector name is displayed when using lm? It seems to work for matrices but not for vectors.

In practice, I would like the code to check where a vector is equal to one, and use this information to name the variable.

Here is an example with a matrix where it works:

```
y <- replicate(1, rnorm(20,0,1))
x <- rep(0,20)
x <- cbind(x, rep(0,20))
x[10,1] <- 1
x[15,2] <- 1
x_names <- which(x==1,1)
x_names #produces: 10, 15
colnames(x) <- x_names[,1]

reg <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(reg) #reports the results for x15 and x10
```

The results are reported as "x10" and "x15".

Here is an example with a vector where it does not work:

```
y <- replicate(1, rnorm(20,0,1))
x <- rep(0,20)
x[10] <- 1
x_names <- which(x==1,1)
x_names
names(x) <- x_names

reg <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(reg) #reports the result only for x, not x10
```

In the second case I would like the output to name the variable "x10", but instead it only reports it as "x".

Can someone suggest a solution?

Thank you!

Comment: to whomever downvoted this question:  Notice that the poster is (a) new to SO, (b) has made a sincere effort at posting a solid question (c) you downvoted without leaving any indication as to why {How is that of any help?}

Comment: Thank you for the comment Ricardo, should I have posted the question somewhere else or phrased it differently?

Comment: nah, you're fine.  someone simply forgot their manners

Answer (score 1):

notice that in the second instance you not naming the collection of variables, but rather each individual element. (However, since you are assigning only a single name to a collection of 10 elements, the rest are getting `NA`s for their name)

`lm` likes data.frames.   Try the following:

```
# creating x, y
x <- rep(0, 20)
x[[10]] <- 1

dat <- data.frame(NameForX=x, y)

lm(y~NameForX, data=dat)
```

replacing NameForX in the two lines above with whatever suits you

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way you could think of without having to use data frames? If not, then I will just have to stick with those.